# How to hover zoom a image using Elevatezoom without using large or small image/ Single image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've a project in which they use only sing. But the image is of high quality. I want to zoom this image using elevate zoom or any similar by just using this one image. Below is a simple UI of zoom

[image]

```
<script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
  zoomType              : "lens",
  lensShape : "round",
  lensSize    : 200
});
```

Comment: May i ask you why you want to avoid using 2 images? is this for better performance or simply for layout/display?

Comment: it's because in my project there is a lot uploading that happens and it's just saved as a single image of HQ.so i've to make some deep changes also if i've to use 2 images

Comment: where is the code? share your working code or code you have done till now. the proper code. don't just come here ask question without code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="thumb-holder">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://www.guthriegreen.com/sites/default/files/Kung-Fu-Panda-6%5B1%5D.jpg">
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.thumb-holder{
  border:4px solid #ff07ee;
  padding:0;
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  margin:15% auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  .thumbnail{
    float:left;
     width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
.thumb-zoom{
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border:4px solid #141414;
  top:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor:none;
  #zoom-img{
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

**The JS**

```
$(".thumb-holder").append('<div class="thumb-zoom"></div>')

$( ".thumb-holder" ).mousemove(function(event) {

    var offset =  $(this).offset();
    var zoomX = event.pageX - offset.left - 50 ;
    var zoomY = event.pageY - offset.top  - 50;



    $('.thumb-zoom').css({
     'left' :zoomX,
     'top': zoomY, 
   })

     var position =  $( ".thumb-zoom" ).position();
     var image = $(".thumbnail").attr('src');

   $('.thumb-zoom').html('<img id="zoom-img" src="'+ image +'" >');

     $("#zoom-img").css({
       'left' : -zoomX - 50 ,
       'top': -zoomY - 50, 
     })

});
```

---

**The Result**

[image]

---

**The Demo**

**Codepen:** [ElevateZoom Lens Effect on hover using one image with JS and CSS](https://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/ZpmoVb)

Comment: i'm not able to understand the code w/o the html part

Comment: @Jeeva are you going to look at this?

Comment: ya!! I didn't try this yet. But i wanted to do it with elevatezoom ..Anyway thanks

Comment: @Jeeva no worries :) But.. "using elevate zoom or any similar"